# FIELD_NOT_FOUND No such struct field error on azure databricks

Tags: python, azure, error-handling, databricks

I have a JSON format dataset, that I am trying to transform using azure Databricks.

I selected the columns that were of interest using the explode function as the json had nested arrays.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, col

items = df.select(explode("items").alias ("items"))
```

using the new dataframe called "items", I then selected the nested object within the array.

```
names = items.select(
    
    col("items.channelId").alias("channel id"),
    col("items.id").alias("id"),
    col("items.kind").alias("kind"),
    col("items.title").alias("title)
    
   
)

display(names)
```

I am now facing an error which is saying  [FIELD_NOT_FOUND] No such struct field "title", even though there is a filed in the dataframe called "title". Please help.

Comment: Provide your sample data.

Comment: "kind": "youtube#videoCategoryListResponse",
 "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/S730Ilt-Fi-emsQJvJAAShlR6hM\"",
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#videoCategory",
   "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/Xy1mB4_yLrHy_BmKmPBggty2mZQ\"",
   "id": "1",
   "snippet": {
    "channelId": "UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ",
    "title": "Film & Animation",
    "assignable": true
   }
  },

Comment: I'm just the the "Items" section with the nested arrays.

Comment: I think I know what the issue is, the "title" is within another nested object "snippet" is the right?

Comment: Yes. title is inside snippet and you need to access by using expr function

Comment: But still you will not get error. It gives null

Answer (score 0):

You load the Json data using below schema and try getting items by `explode` function.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, BooleanType, ArrayType

schema = StructType([
    StructField("kind", StringType(), True),
    StructField("etag", StringType(), True),
    StructField("items", ArrayType(
        StructType([
            StructField("kind", StringType(), True),
            StructField("etag", StringType(), True),
            StructField("id", StringType(), True),
            StructField("snippet", 
                StructType([
                    StructField("channelId", StringType(), True),
                    StructField("title", StringType(), True),
                    StructField("assignable", StringType(), True)
                    ]), True)
            ])
    ), True)
])
```

Load the data as below.

```
json_data ={
    "kind": "youtube#videoCategoryListResponse",
    "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/S730Ilt-Fi-emsQJvJAAShlR6hM\"",
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "youtube#videoCategory",
            "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/Xy1mB4_yLrHy_BmKmPBggty2mZQ\"",
            "id": "1",
            "snippet": {
                        "channelId": "UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ",
                        "title": "Film & Animation",
                        "assignable": "true"
                        }
         },
         {
             "kind": "youtube#videoCategory",
             "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/Xy1mB4_yLrHy_BmKmPBggty2mZQ\"",
             "id": "1",
             "snippet": {
                         "channelId": "UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ",
                         "title": "Film & Animation",
                         "assignable": "true"
                         }
         }
    ]
}

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[json_data],schema=schema)
```

Next, get data as below.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode

items = df.select(explode("items").alias("items"))

display(items.selectExpr(
    "items.snippet.channelId",
    "items.id as id",
    "items.kind as kind",
    "items.snippet.title",
    "items.etag as etag"
    ))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hello, SORRY TO BOTHER YOU, BUT i HAVE ANOTHER ISSUE i WANT TO RESOLVE.

Comment: I HAVE THIS SCHEMAroot
 |-- etag: string (nullable = true)
 |-- items: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- etag: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- kind: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- snippet: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- assignable: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- channelId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- title: string (nullable = true)
 |-- kind: string (nullable = true)

Comment: I want to convert the id into an interger i have the following code

from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
df = df.withcolumn("id"), df "id".cast(integer)

but when i run it i get
ImportError: cannot import name 'intergerType' from 'pyspark.sql.types' (/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py)

Comment: I have this version of pyspark  Python 3.9.5

Comment: try this `df.withColumn("id",col("id").cast("INT")).printSchema()`

Comment: it didn't work. I now have this error  AnalysisException: [UNRESOLVED_COLUMN.WITH_SUGGESTION] A column or function parameter with name `id` cannot be resolved. Did you mean one of the following? [`kind`, `etag`, `items`].;
'Project [etag#2, items#3, kind#4, cast('id as int) AS .id#49]
+- Relation [etag#2,items#3,kind#4] json

Comment: sorry I printed the wrong schema. root
 |-- etag: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- kind: string (nullable = true)
 |-- channelId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- title: string (nullable = true)

Comment: it worked thank you, and sorry again for bothering you